# Generate php docstring

Tags: php, phpdoc, auto-generate, docstring

I recently inherited an existing PHP codebase. The code adheres to PSR-2, but no a single phpdoc comment is present. What i have tried : i ran PHPCS with PEAR standard and i got a list of every comment that would be required. The problem: i have to add them all manually, which is very tedious, and error prone.

I think it might be automated, for example by autogenerating placeholders for  file, class, method and member comments. Then i would just have to edit them instead of building them from scratch.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Generating documentation is always a tedious work...

Comment: Use PHPStorm, write `/**` before method, hit `tab` and you will get generated PHPDoc

Comment: Per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/phpdoc-comments.html, I needed to type `/**` and then hit `Enter`